# Why does $f_{1}(n) = 10n^3 + 5n^2 + 17 \in \theta(n^3)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I saw this in this lecture : [Asymptotic Notation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EL9T1ngiCqA&list=PL7DC83C6B3312DF1E&index=4) at the 15 minute mark. But I don't understand it.
And also why does $f_{2}(n) = 2n^3 + 3n + 79 \in\theta(n^3)$? I don't understand the proof.

Comment: Are you comfortable with limits?

Comment: @jimpix The title isn't supposed to be used as the first line of your question.

Comment: Can you find positive $k_1,k_2,N$ such that $k_1\cdot n^3 \leq 10n^3+5n^2+17\leq k_2\cdot n^3$ for all $n\geq N$?  We don't care about finding the smallest or tightest... we can be very relaxed about it.  How about $k_1=1$ and $k_2=32$ and $N=1$?  Does that work?  What does that imply?

Comment: Out of curiousity, the lecturer already does a good job of explaining the definition of $\Theta$-assymptotic notation.  What **specifically** don't you understand about his explanation?  If you don't specify that, all answers you are likely to receive will be essentially the same as the one you already have available (*and are probably going to be less detailed*).

Answer (score 2):

Until you specify what exactly you don't understand from the video's explanation, I will recap the definitions here.

> We say that a function $f(n)$ is *assymptotically bounded both above and below* by a function $g(n)$ if and only if there exist positive real numbers $k_1,k_2$ and $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $$k_1\cdot g(n)\leq f(n)\leq k_2\cdot g(n)$$
>
> If so, then we write it with symbols as $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$

Informally, we can think of it as though the functions $f$ and $g$ both "grow at the same speed" relatively speaking.  A function like $n^2$ grows *much faster* than a function like $n$, but they are both dwarfed by a function like $n^3$.  On the other hand, a function like $2^n$ grows much faster than the others so far, but that is childs play compared to $3^n$ which is itself nothing compared to $3^{(3^n)}$ which is itself nothing compared to $\underbrace{n^{n^{.^{.^{.^{n}}}}}}_{n~\text{times}}$.  Even bigger and bigger functions can be made.  So, when two "*act pretty much the same*" we like to know it and label it as such.

---

In the examples, we wish to show that $\color{purple}{10n^3+5n^2+17} = \Theta(\color{green}{n^3})$.  That is to say, we want to know if there is some point at which $\color{green}{n^3}$ times some positive constant $\color{red}{k_1}$ will always be *smaller* than $\color{purple}{10n^3+5n^2+17}$, and we also want to know if there is some point at which $\color{green}{n^3}$ times some positive constant $\color{blue}{k_2}$ will always be *bigger* than $\color{purple}{10n^3+5n^2+17}$.

We see that for all positive $n$ (*i.e. for all $n\geq 1$*) one has:

$$\color{red}{1}\cdot \color{green}{n^3}\leq 10n^3\leq \color{purple}{10n^3+5n^2+17}\leq 10n^3+5n^3+17n^3\leq \color{blue}{32}\cdot\color{green}{n^3}$$

Indeed, the inequality holds (*it doesn't even require induction to prove*).  Letting $k_1=1, k_2=32,$ and $N=1$, this shows that $10n^3+5n^2+17$ satisfies the **definition** given above for $10n^3+5n^2+17=\Theta(n^3)$.

---

**Very** *informally*, this should be immediately apparent as the "biggest part" of $10n^3+5n^2+17$ is a constant multiple of $n^3$.  In general, if you have several things being added, you can ignore all of them except the "fastest growing piece" and compare that way.  For example, I know without having to check formally that $34n^7+10n^2-5+\frac{1}{n}$ is in fact asymptotically bounded above and below by $n^7$.  Similarly I know that $34n^7+10n^2-5+\frac{1}{n}$ is **not** asymptotically bounded above and below by $n^2$ (since the $34n^7$ piece grows *much* faster than $n^2$ ever could).

Comment: Thanks! But I don't get the proof.

Comment: @jimpix then please **very specifically** tell me what you don't understand about it and I can try to help you understand.  Do you understand that $n^3\leq 10n^3$?  Do you understand that $10n^3\leq 10n^3+5n^2+17$?  Do you understand that $5n^2\leq 5n^3$?  Do you understand that $17\leq 17n^3$?  Do you understand that $10n^3+5n^2+17\leq 10n^3+5n^3+17n^3$?  Do you understand that $10n^3+5n^3+17n^3=32n^3$?

Comment: @jimpix If you are confused as to why I chose the numbers $1$ and $32$ for $k_1$ and $k_2$ respectively, the answer is that I didn't have to.  I could have chosen **literally any number** so long as $k_1$ was less than or equal to $10$ and $k_2$ was strictly more than $10$.  I would have to use more careful analysis in order to figure out what $N$ would have to be in those cases.  $1$ and $32$ happened to be very convenient because I could use very common tricks to compare the totals (*ignoring terms and changing terms to larger order*).  Just saying you don't understand doesn't help us teach.